# Face recognition ERROR Python OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm having a slight issue with my Face Rec code.
Basically I'm creating a trainer for it. This is my code:

```
import os

import cv2

import numpy as np

from PIL import Image


recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

path = 'D:\OPENCV\Face Recognition\DataSet'


def getImagesWithID(path):

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

    faces = []

    IDs = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        faceImg = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')

        faceNp = np.array(faceImg,'uint8')

        ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath) [-1].split('.') [1])

        faces.append(faceNp)

        print ID

        IDs.append(ID)

        cv2.imshow("training",faceNp)

        cv2.waitKey(10)

    return np.array(IDs), faces


Ids, faces = getImagesWithID(path)

recognizer.train(faces,Ids)

recognizer.save('D:\OPENCV\Face Recognition\Recognizer\trainingData.yml')

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**My error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/OPENCV/Face Recognition/trainer.py', wdir='D:/OPENCV/Face Recognition')
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 87, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "D:/OPENCV/Face Recognition/trainer.py", line 33, in 
>       recognizer.save('D:\OPENCV\Face Recognition\Recognizer\trainingData.yaml')
>
> **error: ......\opencv-2.4.13.2\modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp:390: error: (-2) File can't be opened for writing! in function
>   cv::FaceRecognizer::save**

Could it be something to do with the path??

Thanks in advance,

Srinath

(P.S The code got messed up when i copy pasted. Sorry bout that)

Comment: Maybe some directory is absent in the path you have provided. Try with `recognizer.save('trainingData.yml')`